# Terraform plugin for JQAssistant available?

Tags: jqassistant

I am looking for a terraform plugin for JQAssistant. So far I didn't found any. Is there a plugin available to analyze terraform code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no native support by jQA for analysing Terraform code at the moment. But according to [the Terraform documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/syntax-json.html), it is possible to use JSON as representation format. And jQA supports parsing and analysing JSON via tha [jQAssistant JSON Plugin](http://jqassistant.github.io/jqassistant/doc/1.8.0/#_json_plugin). If you know a tool which is able to convert HCL into JSON, the language used for Terraform, you could try it this way.

As HCL is not so diffuclt, we could consider adding a HCL plugin to jQA.

Comment: I added this as a feature request to our idea hub (https://github.com/jQAssistant/jqa-archivers-plugin/issues/2)

Comment: Sounds good. I already started [a project](https://github.com/kayman-mk/jqa-terraform/) to do this with an ANTLR4 parser. Input and Output variables are working.

Comment: @Matthias That sounds interessting. I also used Antlr for the JSON plugin. If you have a working grammer and some examples, I would be happy to see them.
I could also help you to write a plugin for jQA, if you are interessted.

Comment: @Matthias is working on a plugin for jQA to analyse HCL files. The current repository for this plungin can be found at https://github.com/jqassistant-contrib/jqassistant-hcl-plugin.